# How to enable rfcomm on Linux?

Tags: linux

I am trying to just enable virtual serial port on Linux AKA `/dev/rfcomm0`

I am using "rfcomm" command but it only works in activation of some rfcomm  function.
I do not need that.

I just need to have `/dev/rfcomm0` in the system.

I tried to enable rfcomm and it failed.

`nov25-1@nov251-desktop:~$ systemctl enable rfcomm`

> Failed to enable unit: Unit file rfcomm.service does not exist.
> o.

I am asking for a Linux command to setup `/dev/rfcomm0`  "virtual serial " port on Linux.

Please - your contribution by ANSWERING the question will be greatly appreciated. Replies in style " why would you want to do this " do not help in resolving the issue.

Comment: What would be the purpose of /dev/rfcomm0 _without_ activating "some rfcomm function"? Would it just be a port that does nothing?

Comment: Please contribute by answering the question , derailing  with  pointless discussion does not help.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The `/dev/rfcomm*` devices are designed to mimic a physical serial port connection as much as possible, so each existing `/dev/rfcomm*` device is associated with only one device while it exists. (It's like a serial port with a cable that's plugged into a device.)

If your goal is accepting incoming connections, one device will still accept only one connection at a time: if you want to serve two incoming RFCOMM connections in parallel, you must set up two devices.

Without a `rfcomm` command to describe what you want to do with a particular `/dev/rfcomm*` device, the device won't even be created.

Do you want to accept incoming RFCOMM connections, or to make an outgoing one?

There might be more than one RFCOMM-capable device in range: do you want to allow all of them to connect, or just a specific one?

For outgoing connections, there is no choice: you *must* specify the Bluetooth address of the device you wish to connect to, with:

```
rfcomm connect /dev/rfcomm0 11:22:33:44:55:66
```

This will trigger a connection attempt, and pairing if necessary.

Or if you want to just dedicate `/dev/rfcomm0` to automatically connect to a particular Bluetooth RFCOMM device when some application attempts to use `/dev/rfcomm0`, or to route future incoming RFCOMM connections from a particular Bluetooth device to `/dev/rfcomm0`:

```
rfcomm bind /dev/rfcomm0 11:22:33:44:55:66
```

This will not trigger a connection attempt.

For incoming connections, you have the option of leaving the Bluetooth address of the other end unspecified:

```
rfcomm listen /dev/rfcomm0
```

will accept *one* RFCOMM connection from an unspecified device, and will exit once the connection is terminated.

```
rfcomm watch /dev/rfcomm0
```

will accept multiple RFCOMM connections from unspecified devices, one at a time, until the `rfcomm watch` command is terminated.

---

If you really just need the device node to **exist** without caring about its functionality at all, then you might do a

```
mknod /dev/rfcomm0 c 1 3
```

This will create the device node, and specifies that it will connect to the driver for `/dev/null`; that should be safe.

Comment: Thanks, however, my task is pretty simple - I have an app which lets me to select ports... My system does not have "rfcomm" port as an option. I did try your  way  adding ":rfcomm" as "custom" port and it did not work,  I understand that missing rdcomm port is "normal " in some Linux and there  is a very simple way to add it.,.,.,

Comment: In order to have a working RFCOMM connection, the Bluetooth subsystem absolutely needs to know the Bluetooth address of the other endpoint, and possibly the Bluetooth channel number (defaults to 1 if not specified). The options are: either your application must supply that information, or alternatively you use the `rfcomm` command to set up the connection (creating the `/dev/rfcomm0` device node as a side effect), and then the application will be able to use `/dev/rfcomm0` as if it was a regular wired serial port (if the other device is in range). As far as I know, there are no other ways.

Comment: I have lost my previous notes about this , so I am reposting /. addin to the original post. nov25-1@nov251-desktop:~$ sudo systemctl enable rfcomm
[sudo] password for nov25-1: 
Failed to enable unit: Unit file rfcomm.service does not exist.
nov25-1@nov251-desktop:~$ sudo rfcomm
nov25-1@nov251-desktop:~$ sudo apt install rfcomm
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package rfcomm
nov25-1@nov251-desktop:~$

Comment: My comment n was too long , so I had to edit my original post. I am actually unable to install rfcomm...